# Doctrine, how to join tables with many to many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm working with Symfony 2, Doctrine and Query Builder.
I have 2 tables : product and category.

The product ORM file contains the following :

```
manyToMany:
    categories:
        targetEntity: Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\CategoryInterface
        joinTable:
            name: pim_catalog_category_product
            joinColumns:
                product_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
            inverseJoinColumns:
                category_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
                    onDelete: CASCADE
```

The effect of this is, I have a table named "pim_catalog_category_product" that links categories wih products.
I have no information about products in my category ORM file.

I'm trying to build a query with QueryBuilder and I don't understand how to start with a query on category table, that links products in order to add some filters on products.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->addSelect('category')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'category')
        ->join('Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\Product', 'product', 'WITH', 'category.id IN (product.categories);
```

But for now I get the following error :

```
Expected Literal, got 'product' at ... SELECT category FROM Pim\\Bundle\\CatalogBundle\\Entity\\Category category INNER JOIN Pim\\Component\\Catalog\\Model\\Product product WITH category.id IN (product.categories) at ...
```

Can somebody help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the source of your Category and Product entities?

Comment: Hello. Errors starting with "Expected Literal" usually mean that you used a word that in that query builder(or in the query builder language in general) is reserved for something else. To force query builder to skip the evaluation of that string you can usually use  $qb->expr()->literal('....'), but i don't think this will help in any way in your example. What do you want to get from the QueryBuilder? From the looks of it you are trying to get all categories that have products on them or something like that... Can you go into more details about the purpose of the query?

Comment: @Strnm : the source of those entities is very big, do you need to know something specific ?

Comment: @AlexandruCosoi I need to get all categories with at least one product with a precise parameter. That's why I need to join those table. I have the full query in native SQL, but can't manage to translate it into DQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve my problem with a subquery and the correct way to join a table from a ManyToMany relation.

```
$qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->addSelect('product_category.id')
            ->from('Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\Product', 'product')
            ->join('product.categories', 'product_category');
```

And in my main query :

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('category.id', $qb2->getDQL()));
```

Thank you Alexandru Cosoi and Stmm for the helpful info !

Comment: Congratulations, but keep in mind that although this works for you, it is not the best solution for your problem, doctrine would do it for you if you had your entities properly setup.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ManyToMany doctrine does a lot of 'magic' for you in the background regarding relationship management so you can do fast joins like without needing to take into consideration the cartesian product of the join

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->addSelect('product')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'p')
        ->join('p.category')
```

or fast flush like

```
$product->setCategories($categories);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

The downside is that, in order for doctrine to be able to do this 'magic' you don't have access to the internal join table that you need to do the join that you want.

Also I don't think doctrine can manage this join for you if you don't define the reverse relation on 'category'. But be aware that doing this will be a big memory overhead if you have many product, because doctrine will lazy load all products on your categories.

If you don't want to define the reverse relation (because of the issue mentioned above), an workaround for this is to define an entity on your relation table (something like ProductCategory), and define 2 1->1 relations on the 2 columns of this entity. Then you can use this entity as a bridge whenever you want to create a query builder starting from Category and joining with Product, without having to define the M<->M relation on Category

Something like

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->from($this->_entityName, 'c')
    ->join('Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\ProductCategory', 'pc', 'WITH', 'c.id = pc.category_id')
    ->join('Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\Product', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.id = pc.product_id')
```

PS: try to use short alias like in the above example, to avoid any more "literal" exceptions.

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: I've been searching a lot about QueryBuilder for ManyToMany relationship, and at this point I'm thinking to avoid ManyToMany and create entity for that relation table.